# How to comble find and file command?

Tags: linux, command-line, find

My teacher gave me a homework on combining find and file

> Use find and file to display all files in the /home subdirectory tree,
>   as well as a guess at what sort of a file they are.

I tried using pipeline but it didn't work out as I thought. Any ideas on how to combine both commands? Thanks! =)

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing this on your own?

Comment: Geeze....did you even look at the man pages for `find` and `file` command before asking all of us?  We all don't in general mind helping over hard points but you'll have to show that you have done a little work too.  Afterall if you do not know this stuff, how are you going to make the big bucks....:-)

Comment: @mdpc: Which student reads manuals/books?

Comment: Most of them which do not drop out in the first year (except marketing students).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint.  You use the `file` command as an argument of the `find` command.  Below is the output of my `find` command's help.  Take a look at the "actions" section to see how you can use the `file` command with the `find` command.

```
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]

default path is the current directory; default expression is -print
expression may consist of: operators, options, tests, and actions:

operators (decreasing precedence; -and is implicit where no others are given):
      ( EXPR )   ! EXPR   -not EXPR   EXPR1 -a EXPR2   EXPR1 -and EXPR2
      EXPR1 -o EXPR2   EXPR1 -or EXPR2   EXPR1 , EXPR2

positional options (always true): -daystart -follow -regextype

normal options (always true, specified before other expressions):
      -depth --help -maxdepth LEVELS -mindepth LEVELS -mount -noleaf
      --version -xdev -ignore_readdir_race -noignore_readdir_race

tests (N can be +N or -N or N): -amin N -anewer FILE -atime N -cmin N
      -cnewer FILE -ctime N -empty -false -fstype TYPE -gid N -group NAME
      -ilname PATTERN -iname PATTERN -inum N -iwholename PATTERN -iregex PATTERN
      -links N -lname PATTERN -mmin N -mtime N -name PATTERN -newer FILE
      -nouser -nogroup -path PATTERN -perm [+-]MODE -regex PATTERN
      -readable -writable -executable
      -wholename PATTERN -size N[bcwkMG] -true -type [bcdpflsD] -uid N
      -used N -user NAME -xtype [bcdpfls]

actions: -delete -print0 -printf FORMAT -fprintf FILE FORMAT -print
      -fprint0 FILE -fprint FILE -ls -fls FILE -prune -quit
      -exec COMMAND ; -exec COMMAND {} + -ok COMMAND ;
      -execdir COMMAND ; -execdir COMMAND {} + -okdir COMMAND ;

Report (and track progress on fixing) bugs via the findutils bug-reporting
page at http://savannah.gnu.org/ or, if you have no web access, by sending
email to <bug-findutils@gnu.org>
```

.

Answer (score 0):

You should do your homework but anyway is your problem...

```
find /home -type f -exec file {} \;
```

-type specifies the result (f for file)
-exec executes a program 
{} Is the name of file

Comment: That is very inefficient as the for EACH file you generate a new process.  Think man think...and use xargs!

Comment: @mdpc Or GNU `find` with `-exec file '{}' \+`

Answer (score 0):

Better and more efficient solution:

```
 find /home -type f -print0 | xargs -0 file
```

The above implementation assumes a later version of find and a Linux implementation.  -print0 allows for those cases where special reserved characters are contained in the filename...you know like SPACES!